# Ruby equivalent of ActiveRecord Group by query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to perform an operation on a array returned from an ActiveRecord query. This is the functionality I would have done on the ActiveRecord directly.

```
Modification.find(:all, :group=>'ref_id,start_date', :order=>'updated_at desc')
```

The above is working fine as expected. But the problem is I cannot perform it directly for some reasons. But I have an array. I cannot use `:group` symbol on an array for the obvious reason that is not an ActiveRecord. But I would want the same functionality. Something like

```
modifications = Modification.all
modifications.find(:all, :group=>'ref_id,start_date').sort(:order=>&:updated_at)
```

The above one would not work for obvious reasons, but how to do a similar ActiveRecord implementation for the Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort before group:

```
modifications.group_by{|modification| "#{modification.ref_id}#{modification.start_date}"}.values.collect{|modification_array|
  modification_array.sort_by{|mod| mod.updated_at}.last
}
```

If you want to sort after:

```
modifications.group_by{|modification| "#{modification.ref_id}#{modification.start_date}"}.values.map(&:first).sort_by{|mod| mod.updated_at}.invert
```

Haven't tested :).

Comment: Sweet, didn't realise ruby had a group_by (http://rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=M003084&name=group_by). I think the sort_by needs to be on the final array though, i.e. the result of the group_by, rather than on the individual groups (or maybe as well as).